# How to compare two tables in SQL?

Tags: sql

For example, I have two tables, one of them I have the product description, in another I have data like "price", "date of registration", among others. I would like to know how I can delete the description that does not have id in the product table.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Also, tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to see How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Comment: Alright, Thanks Gordon!

Comment: So one table is the product table with one record per product where we find product description etc. The other is what exactly? A table holding one record per product and an as-of-date with the Information what values are valid for the product as of the date? (So we see a history of prices etc.?) Or what else? In simple words: the other table has one record per _______. (Please fill in the gap.)

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
delete from ProductDescription
where productId not in (
    select productId from Product
);
```

Comment: @Vinicius Rosa: It should not even be possible for a product description entry to exist when the product does not. Obviously your database lacks foreign key constraints.

Comment: There is a slightly hidden check underneath the up and down arrows to the left of my answer's, tick this to accept an answer. Also, consider upvoting answer you find good/helpful.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I set my foreign key as disabled

Answer (score 0):

Consider if we have two tables

```
    Product table
    Id-----Description
 ---------------------------------
    1------It is abcd
    2------It is Efg
    3------It is Xyz
    Product table
    Id------Name------price---date
 -----------------------
    1-------Abcd------10-----1/1/2007
    2-------Efg------20-----2/2/2007
```

We need to delete decription 'Its xyz' which doesnot have id in product table.
So use this query

```
delete from Description
where Id not in (
    select Id from Product
);
```